# Network not working after fiddling with webmin

Tags: networking, routing

Can some please help me restore my networking? I have a VPS CentOS 6.3. Few minutes ago it was working well, Except I couldn't connect to the Yum repository. So I thought I could change some settings in Hostname and DNS Client under webmins network configuration. I  changed the nameserver IP order (8.8.8.8, 0.0.0.0, 66.215.210.17) and also I have removed routing and gateways IP (* more later). Now I can't connect from terminal.

Few minutes back (from terminal using putty):

```
# host 66.215.210.17
17.210.215.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer unknown.hostforweb.net.
```

Now (only from hosting VPS Java client console)

```
# host 66.215.210.17
Host 17.210.215.66.in-addr.arpa not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

I have removed routing and gateways IP, because the IP there was `17.210.215.66`. I remember changing by myself from `0.0.0.0`, earlier. Instead of putting back `0.0.0.0` I left it empty and applied the change. My Bad!

How can I reset it back?